# How to manipulate Angular Animations parameters?

Tags: angular, angular-animations

Okay we have an animation which looks like this:

```
export const scaleDownLeft = animation( [
    query(':enter, :leave', style(sharedStyles)
        , { optional: true }),
        group([
          query(':enter', [
            animate('{{timing}}s {{delay}}s ease-in', keyframes([
             style({transform: 'translateX(-100%)', offset: 0}),
             style( { transform: 'translateX(0%)', offset: 1})
            ])
            )
          ], { optional: true }),
            query(':leave', [
            animate('{{timing}}s {{delay}}s ease-in', keyframes([
              style({ opacity: '1', transform: 'scale(1)', offset: 0}),
              style({ opacity: '0', transform: 'scale(0.8)', offset: 1})
            ]))
          ], { optional: true }),
        ]),
    ], {params: {timing: '0.5', delay: '0'}});
```

As you can see I am passing parameter timing to animate function but in the  query(':leave) section want 0.6 instead of 0.5 so something like this

```
animate('{{timing + 0.1}}s {{delay}}s ease-in'
```

But unfortunately angular throws error *'The provided timing value is invalid.'*

**Note**: I don't want to provide timing separately for each query.

Is any workaround for this ?

Stackblitz: [Demo Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-transition-playground-mlizkr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fanimations.ts)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do operations between {{ }}.

Instead you can simply declare a variable **timing** :

```
let timing = 0.5;
```

and use it like this :

```
animate(timing + 0.1 + 's {{delay}}s ease-in', keyframes([
```

I hope this solution suits you.

Comment: Hi. But when trying to use variable from params. it says 'cannot find name timing'.             animate(timing + 0.1 + 's {{delay}}s ease-in', keyframes...

Comment: maybe I can interact with params globally ?